# How to extract next word after substring that is of variable length? - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have text in one column `col` resembling,

```
{insert random junk text here} FROM db_name.table_name {insert random junk text here}
```

I need to extract `db_name.table_name` and have that stored in a column by itself. Note that `db_name.table_name` is of variable length.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT substring(col, strpos('FROM ', col), strpos(' ', col) - strpos('FROM ', col) + len(' '))
```

This simply just extracts the first character of junk in the column. If someone can help me out with this, that would be great!

**Edge Case**

In some instances, there may be multiple `FROM` keywords. Here I need to extract all three `db_name.table_name`s in separate rows.:

```
{insert random junk text here} FROM db_name1.table_name1 {insert random junk text here} FROM db_name1.table_name2 {insert random junk text here} FROM db_name1.table_name3 {insert random junk text here}
```

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: @RicardoFrancois, why are you trying to use SQL Server syntax if you are using PostgreSQL?

Comment: Ah that could be why I'm getting the error @DavidדודוMarkovitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_matches` to find all occurences of `FROM`, followed by a text containing no space (the table name) and to return the found text

```sql
with src(txt) as (values ('{insert random junk text here} FROM db_name1.table_name1 {insert random junk text here} FROM db_name1.table_name2 {insert random junk text here} FROM db_name1.table_name3 {insert random junk text here}'))

select unnest(regexp_matches (txt, 'FROM ([^ ]+)','g')) from src;

        unnest
----------------------
 db_name1.table_name1
 db_name1.table_name2
 db_name1.table_name3
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Really was hoping this would work, but I'm getting an error saying `Unknown database function 'regexp_matches'`. Could this be because I'm using Redshift?